# As a hobbyist, what do you want in a hardware dev kit for .Net Micro Framework?

Tags: embedded, .net-micro-framework

As a hobbyist that works on embedded systems/robotics.  What would you like to see as hardware features of a Micro Framework development kit?  I have seen plenty of questions about what is available, and nothing really about what is missing.  I also find most existing kits to be aimed more at product development than the hobbyist.

Are modular designs using IDC/jumper blocks better or do you prefer built in components?  How many GPIO pins? Would some form of memory mapped devices be useful? Would you see a use to more than one SPI bus?  What wireless/serial protocols would you like to see?

Comment: @Sinan Unur: Thanks for the fix... I thought I spell checked this before I posted but it looks like I missed one

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about things like the [FEZ boards](http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/) or [Netduino](http://www.netduino.com/)?

I think they've done some insanely great work.

Comment: Really I was thinking of designing my own and was looking for the features that people would like.  I'd like to see the hobby of personal electronics building grow back to its former glory.

Comment: Just cautioning against reinventing the wheel.  For maximum flexibility, add an FPGA surrounded by various drivers (CMOS, TTL, servo, motor, etc.), which would provide endless I/O capabilities.  Each capability would consist of loadable FPGA code combined with a .NET assembly to access it.  Won't be the cheapest solution, but it could be the 'ultimate' board...

Answer (score 1):

For robotics I would like the development board to have a built in H-bridge (for motor control), I2C, SPI, serial, small LCD (for menus, etc.), ZigBee and/or Bluetooth.

Comment: Would you want a motor controller really on board or something similar to the modules like are available for the BASIC Stamp?  My concern with on board would be if you accidentally fry the H-Bridge you would lose part of the board.  As well as this may not upscale well to larger motors and would be of no use for steppers.

Comment: put the H-bridge on a plug in module/card such that _when_ you fry it, its easily replaceable.

Answer (score 1):

I've always loved my Parallax Development board.  I couldn't find the exact one i bought a few years ago... but this is close.

http://www.parallax.com/StoreSearchResults/tabid/768/List/0/SortField/4/ProductID/123/Default.aspx?txtSearch=Prototype+board

To improve upon it, it'd be nice if it had a some more opamps.  I like how you have all the peripherals around the outside that you can quickly wireup to the breadboard.